# How to return multiple matches on a regexp in Java

Tags: java

The thing I don't know how to do it is to store and print the multiples matches it could be.

Like in the example I've here it should return both of the dates fixed "12-21-1990 01-25-1999" but it returns just the second one.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern; 

public class ExamenRegulares{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        String param = "21-12-1990cA  25-01-1999";
        String res = ""; 

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{2})(-)(\\d[1-2])(-)(\\d[19]\\d{2})");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(param);

        while(m.find()){
            res = m.group(3) + m.group(2) + m.group(1) + m.group(4) + m.group(5);
        }
        System.out.println("Original:  " + param);
        System.out.println("Result:  " + res);
    }
}
```

Comment: use `res += ...`, currently you're just reasigning the found match to `res` and overwriting the previous value

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I needed. I knew it was just a little thing that I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're printing it outside the `while` loop, so it will only print the last result.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `while` loop you have

```
res = m.group(3) + m.group(2) + m.group(1) + m.group(4) + m.group(5);
```

This will assign a **new** value to `res` each time, overwriting anything that may have been stored there during earlier iterations of the loop.

In order to fix this, I would consider declaring `res` as a list (and initialising it as empty); then, inside the while loop you append to the list.  When the loop exits, `res` will contain every match (possibly zero).

You will of course have to think about how to handle this in your output, as currently you're assuming just a single result.  But you'll have all of the results available in order to do this, so this is a just a design decision at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Add all the finds to a list, and print the list in the end.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ExamenRegulares{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        String param = "21-12-1990cA  25-01-1999";        

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{2})(-)(\\d[1-2])(-)(\\d[19]\\d{2})");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(param);

        List<String> solutions = new ArrayList<>();
        while(m.find()){
            solutions.add(m.group(3) + m.group(2) + m.group(1) + m.group(4) + m.group(5));
        }
        System.out.println("Original:  " + param);
        System.out.println("Result:  " + solutions);
    }
}
```